# Checking of User Access Rights for Changing/Editing Database Record - ASP.Net C# Logic

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a to-do collaboration web application. Owner of the task add users who can edit that task. Inside database I have a main table for all tasks having create user id and second table mapping other users with a task i.e TaskId, UserId, OwnerId.

In c# I retrieve records through entity framework. To check whether user has access to requested task, I query for task having CreateUserId equals currentUserId or task mapping table has userId equals CurrentUserId of said Task. See my actual query below:

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
var task = db.TblTasks
            .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.Id &&
            (x.UserId == userId || x.TaskMembers
            .Any(i => i.TaskId == x.Id && i.UserId == userId && i.Approved == true)
                 ));
```

While this is working but I am not so sure that my database design or C# logic is correct to handle this nature of work. Please advise me if I can improve it further or any other best practice or professional approach can be implemented

Comment: This question is probably better suited for [the code review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)